# Best algorithm (Time Complexity) to find Minimum spanning tree of an complete, positive weighted, undirected, graph

Tags: graph-theory, trees

Suppose that we have a complete undirected positive weighted graph G={V,E} and I want to find one MST of it. My problem is what is the best (in time complexity) algorithm for it?
The best prime complexity is O(V^2)
The best Kruskal complexity is O(E.Log(E))=~O(V^2. Log(V))
any idea for lower time complexity?

Comment: To calculate a MST you'll have to look at least once at each edge, giving you already $O(E)$. So if you say  $|E|\approx |V|^2$, then that bound you've found for Prim is tight, unless you give more prerequirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted my question in computer science part and [this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/133664/129927) is a resonable answer that I found:

Answer (score 0):

I believe there are deterministic linear time algorithms for sufficiently dense (such as complete) graphs.

One example is Prim's algorithm using a d-ary heap

See end of intro in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prim%27s_algorithm

And another one using Fibonacci heaps: https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/28869.28874

Edit: Linear in the number of edges (i.e. quadratic in vertex number)

Comment: Thanks but as I said in the question I try to find <O(V^2).